# Changing subview frames within UIScrollView on rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, rotation, subview

I have rows of subviews within a UIScrollView that I want to rearrange after rotating to landscape mode.  Ideally, I want to have 5 buttons per row with the total number of rows determined by the button height and how many buttons there are total (plus some padding).

The problem I am having is how to iterate through subviews while also iterating through x-position for 5 buttons on the row and then changing y-position after I hit the 5 button limit to start a new row.

Right now I can iterate through subviews, but I'm not sure how to automate setting the frame for 5 per row and then changing the y-position to start a new row.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
for (UIView *subview in someScrollView.subviews)
{
        if (subview.tag >= 100) {

            [subview setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
            NSLog(@"%.1f %.1f %d %d on subview %d", x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, subview.tag);

        } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dun' figured it out... thanks all the same.

For portrait mode:

```
    for (UIView *subview in outletScrollView.subviews)
    {
        if (x <= 320 && subview.tag != 0) {

            [subview setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
            //NSLog(@"%.1f %.1f %d %d on subview %d", x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, subview.tag);

            x = x + buttonWidth + gapX;

            if (x == 320) {
                x = gapX;
                y = y + buttonHeight + gapY;
            }

        }

    }
```

For landscape mode:

```
    for (UIView *subview in outletScrollView.subviews)
    {
        if (x <= 480 && subview.tag != 0) {

            [subview setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
            //NSLog(@"%.1f %.1f %d %d on subview %d", x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, subview.tag);

            x = x + buttonWidth + gapX;

            if (x == 480) {
                x = gapX;
                y = y + buttonHeight + gapY;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How did you made sure scrollview will not reset frames when scrolling,

Comment: This was before autolayout existed, so you didn't have to since setting the frame was permanent.  (note: this answer was from 3.5 years ago).  With autolayout, you either need to disable it or you have to update the constraints to ensure they stay